# Display latest added/edited data on data grid view

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have an adding and editing station.
However, I want the users to be able to see what they have recently done in the DataGridView.
Say, I added 2 new data. Then on the DGV below, if ever I have some existing data, *only* the 2 new data will be shown. Or, if I edited 5 data, instead of DGV showing the whole table, I want the user to be able to see the 5 data that he edited.
How to do this?
**UPDATE:** I am not coding the DGV, its bounded on the Access Database.

Comment: Show your existing code

Comment: When you say data, do you mean entire row? single cell?
If I understand you correctly, you would like to hide the data? When it should get back?

Comment: I have bounded the DGV to the db, and then, I am just deleting the columns that the user doesn't need to see. So, when there is an activity, if the user saves, I wanted to only display the entire row of the data that he save/edited on that particular time then before he closes.

Comment: Can't you just create an IEnumerable of the new data and change the DGV datasource to it and rebind? P.S. This seems a counter intuitive operation to me.

Comment: Well, this is only a luxury, the user didn't tell me about this, but this would pretty much help them in managing their data. So there's no way of doing this in DGV properties? What you are saying is, I need to unbind the DGV then show them a list where its items are the data they have entered. Am I right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the recent operation grid with a list. 
Add recently updated data to that list.
If the user closes then the list get cleared.
Hope this will help you .